# how can i display data from a model that has a foreinkey relationship

Tags: python, html, django

I have a django shop model and a command model who has a foreinkey relationship to the model shop

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name='nom')
    adress= models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='adresse')
    description=models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    logo=models.ImageField( blank= True ,null=True )
    horaire=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, blank= True , null=True ,verbose_name="utilisateur", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='date de création')
    data=models.JSONField(null=True,blank=True)
        
    
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.name)
```

```
class Command(models.Model):
    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        PENDING = "PENDING"
        REJECTED = "REJECTED"
        CANCELED = "CANCELED"
        PROCESSING = "PROCESSING"
        READY = "READY"
        DELIVERED = "DELIVERED"

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(
        Cart, verbose_name="panier", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    data = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices=Status.choices, default="PENDING")
    shop= models.ForeignKey(Shop, null=True , blank=True, verbose_name="boutique", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    company = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    appartement = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
   # payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment, verbose_name="Payment", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    note = models.TextField(default='', null=True)
    
    home_delivery = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) or 'Anomyne'
```

I want to display the order data and save when placing an order ,all give show except foreignkey part for model shop. how to manage to display this so that each order can then have a specific shop because in this way the order does not register the shop

here is my view file

```
def command(request):
    user = request.user
    COUNTRIES_LIST = COUNTRIES
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data=request.POST
        print(data)
        
        cart_id = request.COOKIES.get('cart_id')
        if cart_id and Cart.objects.filter(id=cart_id).exists():
            command = Command(
                user=user, 
                cart_id=cart_id, 
                name='{0} {1}'.format(data['first_name'], data['last_name']),
                email=data.get('email'),
                phone=data['phone'],
                company = data.get('company'),
                address = data['address'],
                appartement = data.get('appartement'),
                city = data['city'],
                country = data['country'],
                note = data.get('note'),
                shop= data.get('shop')
            )
            
            print('voila bro____________', command)
            
            if data.get('alternate_shipping_address') and data.get('alternate_shipping_address') == 'on':
                command.phone = data['other_phone']
                command.address = data['other_address']
                command.appartement = data['other_appartement']
                command.city = data['other_city']
                command.country = data['other_country']
                command.shop= data['other_shop']
               
                
            command.home_delivery = data['home_delivery'] and data['home_delivery'] == 'on'
            command.save()
            
            for cart_product in command.cart.cart_products.all():
                CommandProduct.objects.create(user=request.user, command=command, cart_id=cart_id, product=cart_product.product, quantity=cart_product.quantity)
            
            command.cart.cart_products.all().delete()
            
            return redirect('payment')
    return render(request, 'command/command.html', locals())
```

HTML file

```
       <div class="axil-checkout-billing">
                                <h4 class="title mb--40">Détails de la facturation</h4>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Prénom <span>*</span></label>
                                            <input name="first_name" value="{{user.username}}" type="text" id="first-name" placeholder="Adam">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Nom <span>*</span></label>
                                            <input name="last_name" value="{{user.last_name}}" type="text" id="last-name" placeholder="...">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                       </label> <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="id_shop">Shop:</label>
                                            <select name="shop" id="id_shop">
                                                {% for shop in shops %}
                                                    <option value="{{ shop.id }}" {% if command.shop_id == shop.id %}selected{% endif %}>{{ shop.name }}</option>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </select>
                                            <button type="submit">Save</button>
                                        
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Nom de l'entreprise (Optionnel)</label>
                                    <input name="company" value="{{user.company}}" type="text" id="company-name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Votre adresse <span>*</span></label>
                                    <input name="address" value="{{user.address}}" type="text" id="address1" class="mb--15"
                                        placeholder="Numéro de maison et nom de la rue">
                                    <input name="appartement" type="text" id="address2"
                                        placeholder="Appartement, suite, unité, etc. (optionnel)">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Ville <span>*</span></label>
                                    <input name="city" value="{{user.city}}" type="text" id="town">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Pays <span>*</span></label>
                                    <select name="country" id="Region" value="33">
                                        {% for country in COUNTRIES_LIST %}
                                        <option value="{{country.code}}" {% if country.code == '243' %}selected{% endif %}>{{country.name}} ({{country.code}})</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Téléphone <span>*</span></label>
                                    <input name="phone" value="{{user.phone}}" type="tel" id="phone">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Adresse Mail (Optionnel)</label>
                                    <input name="email" value="{{user.email}}" type="email" id="email">
                                </div>
                                {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
                                <div class="form-group input-group">
                                    <input name='create_account' type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
                                    <label for="checkbox1">Créer un compte</label>
                                </div>
                                {% endif %}
                                <div class="form-group different-shippng">
                                    <div class="toggle-bar">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle-btn">
                                            <input name="alternate_shipping_address" type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
                                            <label for="checkbox2">Expédier à une adresse différente?</label>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
```

nothing worked in everything i tried

Comment: Try {% for shops in shop %}

Comment: it does not work , it does not display anything in the forms